# Building and uploading TeamCity plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, build, compilation, teamcity

I want to upload [Deployer](https://bitbucket.org/nskvortsov/deployer) plugin to TeamCity server. As readme says I should just copy zip archive into TeamCity plugin folder. Repository contains Maven project but `mvn package` compiles several zip archives. If I upload one of the files plugin appears in the list of plugins(with n/a version and vendor) but does not appears in building steps configuration.

Should I compile it in other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out right zip archive %)

`/deployer/target/deploy-runner.zip`

Comment: @qujck sorry, can't recall. I suppose after building package I got several zip files and only one should be used.